# My bullet keeps going up

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

my bullet keeps firing up
I have implemented a bullet in the following manner, but it seems to just go up, what did i do wrong?

```
public class Player1Controls : MonoBehaviour {

 // Update is called once per frame 
 public float speed;
 Rigidbody2D player;
 public float health;
 private int state;
 public Rigidbody2D Bullet;
 public GameObject Gun;
 void Start ()
 {
     player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
 }
void Update ()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     {
     Rigidbody2D bullet1 = (Rigidbody2D)Instantiate (Bullet, Gun.transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
 }
 if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
 {
     //transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
     player.velocity =(Vector2.up*speed);
     state = 1;
 }
```

public class MoveBullet : MonoBehaviour {

```
 public float speed;
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     Vector3 pos = transform.position;
     Vector3 vel = new Vector3(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
     pos = pos + transform.rotation * vel;
     transform.position = pos;
 }
```

Comment: You set the velocity in the y-direction only. It should be along the vector of your player.

Answer (score 1):

use x and z on the vector3. in unity y is upwards while z is "forward" (into the scene)

Answer (score 0):

Is your bullet shot upwards (as if the weapon is pointing at the sky)? Or is the aim slightly off, and the bullet ends up higher than it should? If you're in the first case, make sure that your variable Vector3 vel's y and z coordinates match your camera's. Its values are zero for X and Z, and a non-zero value in Y. This is may be ok if your scene is set up with The Z-axis pointing up to the sky (and Y-axis pointing into the screen). But if your Z is pointing, say out of the screen and your Y is pointing towards the sky, that would cause the behavior you're seeing.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The plan is to always shoot in the same direction, straight in the Y, but to just rotate the bullet so that the straight is the right kind of straight if that makes sense? I've edited the code to what i've added and removed. What i really want to know i think is how to work out the value for the 3rd property of the instantiate based on the key pressed before the fire, what makes it worse is that i dont even know how to create a rotation variable